# use this.argu to store arguments a good practice?

Tags: javascript, arguments

i am new to front-end developing,and now i am reading a lot of js code written by other in my company and find they will use this syntax to store the arguments :

```
function func1(argu1,argu2){
   this.argu1 = argu1;
   this.argu2 = argu2;
   // other code run here....
}
```

for me i usually skip this and use the argument directly in my code or get a variable for the n,like this:

```
function func2(argu1,argu2){
   alert(argu1);
   alert(argu2);
   var arguOne = argu1,arguSec = argu2;

  // other code run here...
}
```

so i want want to ask why use this syntax to store an arguments?
is this a good practice ?and why?
Have i ever miss some concepts that i should know?

see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/strangeline/T29vd/), written by the my co-worker who has been no longer a front-ender....

Comment: Why would you want to "store arguments"?

Comment: Are the function names capitalized by any chance? If this is meant to be a constructor function, then calling it `func1` instead of `Func1` is bad practice.

Comment: @Pointy i don't know, this is just what my colleague wrote,i have asked him,he said it's convenient to get arguments...since i am not a JS Pro, so i asked here....

Comment: Could you provide some more information? if it's just any old function then `this.argu` will be attached to the global (window) object, which is not a good approach. In case of callback functions or event handlers, it could well be acceptable, but I'd still stay you're better of using closures

Comment: @Esailija all the code i can remember is just a slideshow which is not using any constructor method....so now i think it's just a mistake my co-worker have made...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/strangeline/T29vd/), now my job is to rewrite all the code .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, func1 can be used to create objects. It is effectively a class definition (constructor). It can be used as follows:

```
function func1(argu1,argu2)
{
   this.argu1 = argu1;
   this.argu2 = argu2;
}

var instance = new func1('a', 'b');
alert(instance.argu1);
alert(instance.argu2);
```

Comment: thanks! see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/strangeline/T29vd/) whicn wrote by my co-worker who has been no longer a front-ender, i don't think it will be a be class definition by any chance....

Comment: @strangeline indeed not, he is either deliberately or accidentally creating global variables. And global state is not a good practice.

Comment: @Esailija really thanks! i doubt this for quite a long time since he is my superior before..and quite sure about his theory"it's convenient to store arguments this way"....

Answer (score 1):

Lordy lord: Instead of defining the function, and calling it at the end, try using a closure. Just keep the function definition as is, but put it in brackets:

```
(function new_slider (arguments)
{
    //your code here
})('#new_slider',1500,150,10);
```

This way, the function is declared, and invoked at the same time, all functions defined within the main `new_slider` function will have access to the arguments. There is absolutely no reason to use `this.argu1` to store these values. If anything, it creates global variables, which is considered bad practice.

Please google closures in JavaScript, they're extremely powerful